# Overload resolution with nested generic lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, sfinae, overload-resolution

I'm trying to create a recursive overload-set utility, such that you can for example access `this` inside of a lambda (like the [deducing_this](https://wg21.link/p0847) proposal). I've stumbled against a problem, though, and I'm not really sure how I can fix or work around this.

I managed to reduce the problem to the following piece of code:

```cpp
template<typename ...Fs> struct overload : Fs... { using Fs::operator()...; };
template<typename ...Fs> overload(Fs...) -> overload<Fs...>;

int main() {
  auto f_int    = [](int)    {};
  auto f_double = [](double) {};

  auto f = overload{
    f_int,
    f_double,
  };

  f(0);   // ok
  f(0.0); // ok
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1r4b7Gf3P

So far, no problems.
However, when I wrap the overloads inside of a generic lambda, the overload resolution doesn't seem to be working anymore:

```cpp
  auto f_int    = [](int)    {};
  auto f_double = [](double) {};

  auto f = overload{
    [=](auto x) -> decltype(f_int(x))    { f_int(x);    },
    [=](auto x) -> decltype(f_double(x)) { f_double(x); },
  };

  f(0);   // error: ambiguous call to overloaded function
  f(0.0); // error: ambiguous call to overloaded function
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ahWYzxarc

The previous working code piece works because of the overload resolution: it picks the overload with the least amount of implicit conversions. Unfortunately, that doesn't work here. The SFINAE trick here is also not enough, because there is no SFINAE going on: the double is implicitly converted to an int (a warning may be generated). Therefore, both overloads will be considered.

So my question is this:

- Is there a *generic* way to somehow make overload resolution working in this case, i.e. we have an overload set of some wrapped function for which we don't know whether they will be SFINAE'ed away, and also don't know whether there are implicit conversions going on.

Comment: Uh, `f(0)` is definitely also ambiguous in the second example.

Comment: Also the description isn't right. There is definitely SFINAE going on - it's just that both calls are valid. SFINAE isn't the issue - the issue is that you need to pick which overload gets called for a set of arguments, and there's no way to do that.

Comment: You are right, both cases are ambiguous. I was a bit too quick writing this code here. In my dev environment I was testing it with the double as argument, but obviously the int won't work either. I'll edit my post.

Comment: But regarding the sfinae, there is no substitution failure in this case, right? I just managed to convince myself that by using the trailing return types, I would be able to kick out implicit conversions. But that was a misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a generic way to somehow make overload resolution working in this case

I don't know if you can define it "generic" but... if you transform `f_int()` and `f_double()` in classic functions (no lambda)

```
void f_int (int) {};
void f_double (double) {};
```

and you add deleted template functions with the same names

```
template <typename T>
void f_double (T) = delete;

template <typename T>
void f_int (T) = delete;
```

now SFINAE works as you want (I suppose) because when you call `f_int()` with a `double` (or `f_double()` with an `int`), the matching function is the template deleted one.

This solution doesn't works when `f_int` and `f_double` are lambda variables because the compiler complaints for "redefinition of 'f_double' as different kind of symbol" errors.

The following is a full compiling example

```
template<typename ...Fs> struct overload : Fs... { using Fs::operator()...; };
template<typename ...Fs> overload(Fs...) -> overload<Fs...>;

template <typename T>
void f_double (T) = delete;

template <typename T>
void f_int (T) = delete;

void f_int (int) {};
void f_double (double) {};

int main() {

  auto f = overload{
    [=](auto x) -> decltype(f_int(x))    { f_int(x);    },
    [=](auto x) -> decltype(f_double(x)) { f_double(x); },
  };

  f(0);   // ok
  f(0.0); // ok

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for. Ignoring the fact that it is not generic, it doesn't result in the same overload resolution behavior as in the original code fragment (the one that directly uses the lambdas). If you comment out the overload for the double, both f(0) and f(0.0) should be handled by the int overload. However, in your case f(0.0) fails to compile.